# Setting an attribute in a rails concern

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I set an attribute in a rails concern?

here is my concern:

```
module Nodeable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  def set_lat                
    lat = 5
  end
end
```

And then if i try to use it

```
test = Item.first
test.set_lat
test.save!
```

Check if it worked:

```
test.lat
=> nil
```

Comment: Use explicit self: `self.lat = 5`

Comment: the answer is to have self.lat =  not lat =

Comment: this is a more specific question, much easier to understand than the candidate for duplicate

Comment: That's what I said :)

Comment: Yes, a better dup target undoubtedly exists. But this one is "good enough", I think.

Comment: Unless you use implicit self as mentioned by @sergio-tulentsev you are just assigning a local variable in the method - not the instance variable of the object that includes the module.

Comment: I think I found a better dup @SergioTulentsev

Comment: @max: yep, this one is indeed better. 

Comment: guys,  that isn't a great choice at all.